# Is there a workaround in VBA for sql queries with no results?

Tags: sql, vba, excel, dao, adodb

I have a VBA program in which part of it queries our SQL servers and returns specific data.  The problem is that the data isn't necessarily always there, which is expected.  I need to query the database asking for specific data, and if it isn't there then I want the program to ignore it and move on.  Unfortunately, when I hit a record without data I get the following error:

> Run-time error '3021': 
>   Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted.

a.k.a. there's no record.  Is there a way, without using on error, to either

1. Determine which the data is present, OR
2. just have it return a null string/recordset/*anything* other than an error?

Answer (score 4):

This is the need for testing the RecordCount/EOF to make sure you have records in the recordset before navigating into the opened recordset.

```
Public Sub TestRS()
    Dim rsObj As DAO.Recordset

    Set rsObj = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT FieldName1, FieldName2 FROM tableName WHERE someID = 10")

    If rsObj.RecordCount < 1 Then
        MsgBox "No Records."
        'You can also test using one of the following.
        'If Not (rsObj.BOF And rsObj.EOF) Then
    Else
        MsgBox "There are more than one Record."
    End If
    Set rsObj = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant, totally forgot about the .recordcount property

Comment: I would just note that the `recordcount` property isn't always accurate depending on which rdbms you're using. I personally prefer to use `If Not rsObj.EOF` because you don't really care if you're at the beginning of the file, you just don't want to work past the end of it.

Comment: @RubberDuck As far as I know, if there are records in the recordset .RecordCount always returns >0, so the test is correct. But you are right, to get the actual record count the recordset has to be "populated" first.

Comment: A very valid Statement by @RubberDuck, yes RecordCount would return a -1 for ADO setup, DAO returns 0 for **no records**. However the count will always be > 1 if the recordset returns something. So my checking condition <0 should simply work without a problem !

Comment: That's not true @PaulFrancis. It's a known issue with ADODB that recordcount may not return a recordcount until the cursor has been moved. It does not seem to be an issue for DAO, but we don't know which OP is using.

Comment: Unless as mentioned by @MarekStejskal, if you are actually wanting the count of the records returned, a `MoveLast` and `MoveFirst` would be in order after checking the `BOF And EOF` is **False**.

Comment: @RubberDuck, absolutely true.

Answer (score 1):

Before accessing any field value in resulting recordset, you have to check, is recordset at .EOF or ask records count of it. Just opening empty recordset will not give you error, accessing its records gives.

Without seeing your code (starting from recordset opening) it is hard to write any more specific suggestions.